# Windows Phone 7 Cancel hardware back button not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, cordova-2.0.0

I need to cancel the device back button event. I have tried the solution posted in [Control press "back button" and disable close the application using a dialog for confirm - wp7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741939/control-press-back-button-and-disable-close-the-application-using-a-dialog-for), but it is not working for me. Am I doing something wrong? The application always exits whether ok or cancel is selected from the dialog box.

Here is my code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Resources;


namespace GodTools
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.CordovaView.Loaded += CordovaView_Loaded;

            BackKeyPress += OnBackKeyPressed;

        }

        private void CordovaView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.CordovaView.Loaded -= CordovaView_Loaded;
            // first time load will have an animation
            Storyboard _storyBoard = new Storyboard();
            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                From = 0,
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.6),
                To = 90
            };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, SplashProjector);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("RotationY"));
            _storyBoard.Children.Add(animation);
            _storyBoard.Begin();
            _storyBoard.Completed += Splash_Completed;
        }

        void Splash_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as Storyboard).Completed -= Splash_Completed;
            LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(SplashImage);
        }

        void OnBackKeyPressed(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            var result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit?", "Attention!",
                                          MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

            if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                // Do not cancel navigation
                return;
            }
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

see also, same problem from the Cordova side
["backbutton" event won't fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866952/backbutton-event-wont-fire)

Answer (score 1):

For your information: If you write an application (not an XNA game) you shoul avoid canceling back button. Otherwise your app will be canceled on passing Marketplace sertification.

Also you can override `OnBackKeyPress` method with the same code;

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            var result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit?", "Attention!",
                                          MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

            if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
                return;
            }
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
```

**update**

I've just created a new 'Silverlight for windows phone" solution. Opened MainPage.xaml.cs file and added this code to it:

```
// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BackKeyPress += OnBackKeyPressed;
}

void OnBackKeyPressed(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit?", "Attention!",
                                  MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

    if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
        // Do not cancel navigation
        return;
    }
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

so there is only one page in this project. And it works. The target platform is `Windows Phone OS 7.1`, I've checked it on Mango device and on the standard emulator. I think the problem is somewhere else. Maybe some code crashes you application while you are trying to cancel back event?

Please, try to check it on new simple project.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I do want to make use of the hardware back button. I'm just trying to take things one step at a time. Eventually I need to follow the backbutton event and then perform navigation using javascript. Before I do that I need to cancel the default backbutton behavior.

Comment: Well, anyway your code works for me. Did you tried to put a debuger in OnBackKeyPressed method? does code goes to e.Cancel=true statement when you press cancel button?

Comment: My code does go to e.Cancel and sets it to true, but the application still exits.

Comment: Magic... Ok, I've got a page with clean code-behind. just a subscription to BackKeyPress event. And it works. Let's try to comment this line: this.CordovaView.Loaded += CordovaView_Loaded; did it change something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873086/how-to-handle-the-back-button-on-windows-phone-7?rq=1 look here. Does you app contains only one page??

Comment: My app does only contain one page. Is there a method to override the back button in this case?

Comment: Check Properties of your project. What is written in TargetPlatform dropdown list? and how do you navigate to the first page?